# Cannot emit to a particular room after a socket joins it

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to add chat room functionality to my app. Here, I want to set the projectId as the room ID and want the sockets to join the that room based on the project they are a part of.

```
let roomId;

  io.on("connection", (socket)=>{

    socket.on("join_room_id", ({projectId})=>{

      socket.join(projectId);
      roomId = projectId;
    })

    io.to(roomId).emit("greet", {msg:"hello"}) // doesn't work
```

I think roomId is not being stored correctly hence, my frontend can't receive any message

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`io.on('connection', ...)` is an event handler.  That event occurs one or more times in the future at an unknown time.  So, you can't call `io.to(roomId).emit(...)` at just any time.  You can only call it after a client connects (and before they disconnect).

This concept of declaring `roomId` in the parent scope and setting it's value in some event handler that occurs at an unknown time so you can somehow use it in other places is usually an anti-pattern because the outside code has no way of knowing when the variable is set or not set or is still valid.  And, in your case, one socket connecting will overwrite the previous value of that variable.

If, all you want to do is to send a message to a newly connection socket, then you should move the `.emit()` to inside the `connection` event handler or inside the event that has the data you want to greet after.  When doing it in there, you can just send directly to the appropriate socket too.

```
  io.on("connection", (socket)=>{

    socket.on("join_room_id", ({projectId})=>{
      socket.join(projectId);
      socket.emit("greet", {msg:"hello"});
    });
  });
```

If you want to not emit until after the join is done, then you need to `await` the promise that `.join()` returns.  That operation can be asynchronous and is not guaranteed to be completed when the `.join()` returns.